# Where, when and what is the word 圆舞 used for?

Tags: word

I've heard people call Waltz (music) either 华尔兹 or 圆舞曲, but I've only heard people call Waltz (dance) 华尔兹, never 圆舞.

According to [Baidu](http://baike.baidu.com/view/1608388.htm), 圆舞 does have a meaning of Waltz (dance). It has another meaning of some country/ceremonial dance, seems to suggest this word had been existed before Waltz was imported.

I see this word used as 亦舒's book title, but having not read that book, I don't know if the usage is captured from real life experience or rather fictitious.

Since I've never heard this word used in my daily life, not even from the elders, I am wondering if this word is still used at all. If yes, in which Chinese-speaking region is it used and which meaning of the two does it refer to? If no, was this word ever a common word (when?) and which meaning was it used for?

Comment: Looking through some examples of it, it looks like it's a generic term for (as the name implies) a round dance. The Waltz could be called a kind of 圆舞, and it's danced to "round dancing music" (圆舞曲), but it doesn't look like it refers to any specific dance or is commonly used at all.

Comment: I am not familiar with Waltz. It seems the American style mixed Viennese Waltz in 亦舒's novel (couples who wanted to participate were told to change partners about five times during a waltz): `傅于琛拉着我，教我舞步，大家跟着围成一个大环，我与他跳两下，转个圈，随即有别人接过我的手，与我舞到另一个角落去。这是我第一次被当作大人看待，很是投入，舞步十分简单，一学即晓，当我又转到傅于琛身边。大家边笑边跳，舒畅异常。我问他：“可否一直同你跳？” “不，一定要转舞伴。” “为什么？” “这只舞的跳法如此。” “是吗？” “它叫圆舞，无论转到哪一方，只要跳下去，你终归会得遇见我。” “哦，是这样的。” 他呼吸急促，每个人都挥着汗，喘着气，“嗨，跳不动了！” 大家一起停下来，大笑，宽衣，找饮料解渴。这真是一个有趣的游戏，我会牢记在心。它叫圆舞。`

Comment: I seldom hear someone would call Waltz (dance) 圆舞. Google search results also suggest that.

Answer (score 2):

My guess, and I think this is a reasonable good guess is that 华尔兹 = "waltz" and 圆舞 = "round dance" and in English a waltz is a type of round dance.

So you don't hear people calling "华尔兹" "圆舞" because "华尔兹" is a type of "圆舞" but 圆舞曲 can be used for any kind of "圆舞" not just for waltzes.

If you [use Google to search for the definition of round dance](https://www.google.com.au/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=define%3around+dance&oq=define%3around+dance&gs_l=hp.3...462.3321.1.3425.18.18.0.0.0.0.453.5353.3-12j3.15.0....0...1c.1.19.hp.6zpypz24qpk&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.dmg&fp=ab5b7527b514333b&biw=1680&bih=843) you get the following:

> #### round dance
>
> Noun
>
> 1. A folk dance in which the dancers form one large circle.
> 2. A ballroom dance such as a **waltz** or polka in which couples move in circles around the 
>      ballroom.

Also from the [wikipedia article on Round dance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_dance):

> Modern social round dancing is choreographed and cued ballroom dancing
>   that progresses in a circular pattern, counter-clockwise around the
>   dance floor. The two major categories of ballroom rhythm found in
>   round dancing are the smooth or international rhythms, such as foxtrot
>   and **waltz**, and the Latin rhythms, such as cha-cha and rumba.